# Como puedo ocultar un div con CSS 'transition'

Tags: javascript, css

Tengo 2 Divs horizontales (no aparecen horizontales pero si, lo están), necesito ocultar el div izquierdo con transition y dejar el div derecho centrado, la idea es que al apretar un boton que esta en el medio de los dos div, se oculte el div izquierdo.
.
He probado escondiendo el div pero no es la idea, la idea es que tenga la transicion ocultandose.

He probado con de todo y no estoy pudiendo solucionarlo, si alguien me puede dar una mano se lo agradezco de antemano

```css
.col {
  display: flex;
}

.izq {
  margin-top: 20px;
  min-width: 35%;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.der {
  min-width: 60%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.ocultar {
  height: 10%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div className="col">
  <div className="izq">
    <label>izquierdo</label>         
  </div>
  <div>
    <button className="ocultar">Ocultar</button>
  </div>
  <div className="der">
    <label>derecho</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Veo que estás usando React, por lo que puedes crear un método en la clase que agregue o quite la clase `oculto` al apretar el botón. Es muy simple creando un estado de `showIzq` y dependiendo de este estado, insertar o remover la clase que requieres. Te dejo un ejemplo funcional utilizando tu código.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showIzq : true
}

  toggleIzq = () =>{
     this.setState({showIzq: !this.state.showIzq})
  }


  render() {
    return(
    <div className="col">
      <div className={'izq ' +(this.state.showIzq ? '':'oculto')}>
        izquierdo     
      </div>
      <div>
        <button className="ocultar" onClick={this.toggleIzq}>Ocultar</button>
      </div>
      <div className="der">
        derecho
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.col{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
 }
  
  div.izq, div.der{
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background: #1E90FF;
  }
  
  .izq {
    transition: 0.8s;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
  }
  
  .oculto{
  opacity: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

podrias hacer algo como esto

```
<div class='movimiento'>
```

```
 .movimiento{
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  background:red;
  animation: prueba 3s forwards;

  }


@keyframes prueba{
  50%{transform:translateX(-50%)}
  

60%{
opacity:0;
display:none
}
}
```

y manipularlo con el  evento click, asi desapareceras el elemento de una manera no tan brusca

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).